# Create a New Column Based on Some Values From Other Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Imagine that this Data Set:

```
   A
1  2
2  4
3  3
4  5
5  5
6  5
```

I would like to create new column by this condition from A:

```
if A[i] < A[i-1] then B[i] = -1 else B[i] = 1
```

the result is:

```
   A   B
1  2   NaN
2  4   1
3  3   -1
4  5   1
5  7   1
6  6   -1
```

All codes and solutions that I have found just compare the rows in same location.

Comment: have a look at [`pd.Series.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
df['B']=[1 if i!=0 and df['A'][i] < df['A'][i-1] else -1 for i,v in enumerate(df['A'])]
```

or

```
df['B']=[1 if i!=0 and df['A'][i] < df['A'][i-1] else -1 for i in range(len(df['A']))]
```

Edit (for three states like greater, less, and equal):

```py
import numpy as np
df['B']=np.NAN*len(df.a)
for i in range(1,len(df['a'])):
    if df['a'][i] < df['a'][i-1]: df['B'][i]=1
    elif df['a'][i] == df['a'][i-1]: df['B'][i]=0
    else: df['B'][i]=-1
```

Comment: What if we want to have three states like greater,less, and equal?

Comment: I have found, just add parenthesis in else statement :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `diff` function. then the `sign` function:

```
df.assign(B = np.sign(df.A.diff()))

Out[248]: 
   A    B
0  2  NaN
1  4  1.0
2  3 -1.0
3  5  1.0
4  7  1.0
5  6 -1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,4,3,5,7,6]})
df['B'] = np.where(df['A'] < df['A'].shift(1), -1, 1)
```

in order to keep the nan in the beginning:

```py
df['B'] = np.where(df['A'].shift(1).isna(), np.nan, df['B'])
```

Comment: What happen if we want to compare 3 of elements? For example: A[i] < A[i-1] and A[i-1] < A[i-2]